# How to get a simple Bootstrap Site on cloudControl

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, cloudcontrol

I'm trying to deploy a simple Website - a couple of html sites based on twitter-Bootstrap templates - on cloudControl.

Unfortunatelly It seems I can only deploy a Java, PHP, Node.js and some more applications but not just some html sites.

Building a Java or any other application just to show some html sides seems to be an overhead to the scope.

Is there any suggestion how I just can deploy html sites to cloudControl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think NodeJS would be your simplest option. Start with a simple server like this..

https://github.com/spadin/simple-express-static-server

Put your HTML/JS/CSS files in `/static`, and it's ready to deploy

Comment: thanks that worked I did not manage to user a /static folder for the files. Everything is in the /public  folder
Any Idea where I went wrong ?
here is the repository
https://github.com/kenparker/homepagenodejs2.git

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest php, the buildpack automatically provides apache as web server and delivers static html files directly.

In all other cases you have to provide the server by yourself and it seems like you just want some static html pages.